# Token generation entropy equivalent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

This small piece of PHP code generates tokens with very good entropy. I would like to know if there is a function in JavaScript that can accomplish the same. Examples are welcome.

Here's the PHP

```
function getToken($length) {

    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet  = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet .= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet .= "0123456789";

    $max = strlen($codeAlphabet);

    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[random_int(0, $max-1)];
    }

    return $token;
}

echo getToken(24);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing almost the same thing..

```js
function getToken(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

console.log(getToken(10));
```

**Example with Jquery**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

 // set the length of the string
 var stringLength = 10;

 // list containing characters for the random string
 var stringArray = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
  'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','!','?'];

 $("#generateToken").click(function (){

  var rndString = "";
 
  // build a string with random characters
  for (var i = 1; i < stringLength; i++) { 
   var rndNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * stringArray.length) - 1;
   rndString = rndString + stringArray[rndNum];
  };
  
  $("#showToken").html('<p><strong>' + rndString + '<strong></p>');

 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button below to generate a new, randomized token.</p>
<button id="generateToken">Generate New Token</button>
<p id="showToken"></p>
```

Comment: Nice. Since you've mentioned almost, is there a difference worth noting?

Comment: Should be exactly the samething sorry for speling wrong

Comment: At the very least give a reference or close the question as a duplicate when you copy code from a highly upvoted answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: @icecub I got this from a video tuturoial on youtube to use for reseting password about 3 years ago, guy name was JOHN something, didnt see that answer and didnt copy from there. its a token generating script almost all of them are same if you search on internet. Thanks